# Bridge to a Node - Web3

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript, nodes

In my site I call a contract's method that returns me a value, using web3, and then I show the value on screen.
Obviously, if you go on my site you must have installed an ethereum node or a bridge to a node like MetaMask to access contract's call and see the value.
But it is possible to see it without installing anything, only coding a JavaScript bridge to a node? It is possible? It is secure?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible?

web3 is written in javascript, you can write your own javascript code implementing JSON-RPC  protocol.

Metamask uses web3, it has own HD wallet and can connect to local ethereum node as well as infura ethereum nodes.

If you don't want any thing installed, you can use infura ethereum nodes, implement JSON-RPC protocol methods in javascript, and you own HD wallet.(You can implement normal wallet also).

> It is secure?

Security depends on you as an application developer, Metamask and Web3 are here for quite some time, so probably they are more robust and secure.

Answer (score 0):

> if you go on my site you must have installed an ethereum node or a bridge to a node like MetaMask to access contract's call and see the value

I'm not sure what you mean by "my site", but that's not a website in the proper sense of server-client.

It is YOU who have to do all of this, and your server should just receive requests (typically in the form of HTTP) and transmit responses (typically in the form of HTTP).

On each HTTP request from the client, the server shall interact with the node via Web3, in order to obtain the required piece of information from the block-chain and send it in an HTTP response to the client.